# Is there a way to use place holders in Apache PropertiesConfiguration

Tags: java, properties, apache-config

I have the following configuration setup using Apache Configuration:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;

Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");
```

I want to know if there is some way to use place holders in the properties file? For example, I want to have this:

```
some.message = You got a message: {0}
```

And be able to pass in the value for the `{0}` place holder. Typically, you can usually do something like `config.getString("some.message", String[] of values)` but don't see anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Configuration class doesn't provide any formatters. So, for your task

1. You can use MessageFormat as it was suggested by Bilguun. Please
   note, that format method is **static**.
2. You can use `String.format` function.

Examples is bellow:

**config.properties**

```
enter some.message.printf=%1$s\, you've got a message from %2$s \n
some.message.point.numbers =Hey {0}\, you got message: {1}!
```

**Example class**

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class ConfigurationTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
        Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");

        String stringFormat = String.format(config.getString("some.message.printf"), "Thomas", "Andrew");
        // 1 String format
        System.out.println(stringFormat);
        // 2 Message Format
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(config.getString("some.message.point.numbers"), "Thomas", "Hello"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could get property value with placeholder from a property file and then use [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) to formatting the message to what you desired. Let's say you got following property in your property file:

```
some.message = "Hey {0}, you got message: {1}!"
```

So that you get and format this property like:

```
message will be "Hey {0}, you got message: {1}!"    
String message = config.getString("some.message");

MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat("");

//it will print: "Hey Thomas, you got message: 1"
System.out.println(mf.format(message, "Thomas", 1));
```

Also, if you could use system variables or environmental variables if it is not changed on the fly